# Cannot access Amazon s3 file: '403 Forbidden'

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to export my local postgres data to the database in heroku.

So, I dumped my local database and uploaded the `.dump` file to amazon s3.

And as said [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export), I am using the following command to copy to the database in heroku:

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
aborting: could not write to output stream: Expected HTTP Status 200, received: "403 Forbidden"
```

I realize I need to include my `access key` or `secret key` somewhere.

How do I do that?

Comment: does `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY=xxx AWS_SECRET_KEY=yyy` help

Answer (score 0):

Generate s3 secure url temporarily for restore. The S3 complete url will then have query params in form of

?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1367876175&Signature=XXXXXXX%EEEEEEEYWWWWWW

Answer (score 0):

If you don't serve dump file via that url, you can try to scp your dump to a location in your local machine and load to heroku from your local folder. Sample scp code I use for free S3 server is:

```
scp -i /pem/file/location/file.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/file/path/on/amazon/file.dump /path/on/local/
```